# sed replace number with special character except last string in a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a file in Linux like

```
/test/something/test2/2013-10-12/file_123
/test/123456/file_123
/test/test2/test3/test4/something/2013/file_123
```

I want to change it to following format in Linux

```
/test/something/test2/????-??-??/file_123
/test/??????/file_123
/test/test2/test3/test4/something/????/file_123
```

Can I achieve this using sed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kent$  awk -F/ -v OFS='/'  '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9][0-9]/)gsub(/[0-9]/,"?",$i);}7' file
/test/something/test2/????-??-??/file_123
/test/??????/file_123
/test/test2/test3/test4/something/????/file_123
```

Comment: I'm new to linux....could you please explain the usage of the OFS, NF, NR, gsub you used in the above command....That would be great..

Answer (score 0):

If the point is just to remove data:

```
awk -F/ '{$(NF-1)="????"}1' OFS=/ file
/test/something/test2/????/file_123
/test/????/file_123
/test/test2/test3/test4/something/????/file_123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ": do
s|[0-9]\([^/]*/[^/]*\)$|?\1|
t do" YourFile
```

replace any digit in n-1 part of the path